# Response to Remote access to Unet Agents for GNURadio

Tags: unetstack

I was wondering what did the `Unetstack agent` expect as a response to a `TCP connection` which is established to the modem at ip:port ?

I was trying to connect to the the modem using the `TCP connection` through the [GNURadio pdu socket](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Socket_PDU). The connection was established but i think after handshaking, it was automatically terminated. Did it expect something ?I am planning to send custom messages to modem using this APIs.

**Here is what i have done so far**.

1. I opened a `TCP connection` using `Socket PDU` block using below flow graph.

[image: GNURadio Flow graph]

2. I used unet audio SDOAM to test:

```sh
jay@jay-MS-7885:~/Desktop/unet-3.2.0$ bin/unet -c audio
Modem web: http://localhost:8080/
> iface
tcp://10.0.3.1:1100, tcp://192.168.0.14:1100, tcp://192.168.0.165:1100 [API]
ws://10.0.3.1:8080/ws, ws://192.168.0.14:8080/ws, ws://192.168.0.165:8080/ws [API]
unetsh: console://- [GroovyScriptEngine]
websh: ws://127.0.1.1:8080/fjage/shell/ws [GroovyScriptEngine]
```

It looks like the connection was established and on `GNURadio` side in `command prompt` i got normal `JSON response` from modem. And Just after that connection was automatically closed. Did it expect something ?

```
Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/jay/Desktop/Jay/UnetstackPython.py

******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
Send
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a l i v e " :   t r u e } 
])
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a c t i o n " : " s e n d " , " m e s s a g e " : { " c l a z z " : " o r g . a r l . f j a g e . G e n e r i c M e s s a g e " , " d a t a " : { " m s g I D " : " 0 9 f 5 3 2 0 0 - e 2 9 1 - 4 8 2 6 - 8 9 6 b - c 5 d 1 6 5 8 9 f 8 d 5 " , " i n R e p l y T o " : " 3 5 5 8 f e c 9 4 e e 7 b e e 1 a 5 0 f 5 6 6 1 d e 6 f c 4 b d " , " p e r f " : " A G R E E " , " r e c i p i e n t " : " W e b G W - c e a 1 9 a 9 d 3 7 f b e b 0 8 " , " s e n d e r " : " w e b s h " , " a n s " : " a u t o " } } , " r e l a y " : f a l s e } 
])
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a c t i o n " : " s e n d " , " m e s s a g e " : { " c l a z z " : " o r g . a r l . f j a g e . G e n e r i c M e s s a g e " , " d a t a " : { " m s g I D " : " 4 b d 5 6 f 0 7 - d a c 2 - 4 7 2 9 - 8 2 7 6 - b 4 4 1 8 6 d 3 1 6 a a " , " i n R e p l y T o " : " 8 7 7 9 5 2 4 c 4 5 d 8 9 f 1 e 4 6 3 b e 9 8 e 6 4 d 6 0 c e a " , " p e r f " : " A G R E E " , " r e c i p i e n t " : " W e b G W - c e a 1 9 a 9 d 3 7 f b e b 0 8 " , " s e n d e r " : " w e b s h " , " a n s " : " t c p : / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 : 1 1 0 0 ,   t c p : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 4 : 1 1 0 0 ,   t c p : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 6 5 : 1 1 0 0   [ A P I ] \ n w s : / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 : 8 0 8 0 / w s ,   w s : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 4 : 8 0 8 0 / w s ,   w s : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 6 5 : 8 0 8 0 / w s   [ A P I ] \ n t c p : / / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 : 1 1 0 0 / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 . 3 5 9 5 6   [ A P I ] \ n u n e t s h :   c o n s o l e : / / -   [ G r o o v y S c r i p t E n g i n e ] \ n w e b s h :   w s : / / 1 2 7 . 0 . 1 . 1 : 8 0 8 0 / f j a g e / s h e l l / w s   [ G r o o v y S c r i p t E n g i n e ] " } } , " r e l a y " : f a l s e } 
])
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a c t i o n " : " s e n d " , " m e s s a g e " : { " c l a z z " : " o r g . a r l . f j a g e . p a r a m . P a r a m e t e r R s p " , " d a t a " : { " i n d e x " : - 1 , " v a l u e s " : n u l l , " p a r a m " : " o r g . a r l . y o d a . M o d e m P a r a m . n o i s e " , " v a l u e " : - 8 4 2 . 1 , " r e a d o n l y " : [ " o r g . a r l . y o d a . M o d e m P a r a m . n o i s e " ] , " m s g I D " : " c 4 6 8 b 2 8 c - 9 3 8 5 - 4 9 a 3 - 9 c 2 8 - a 8 6 5 e d 7 e 9 8 b c " , " p e r f " : " I N F O R M " , " r e c i p i e n t " : " W e b G W - c e a 1 9 a 9 d 3 7 f b e b 0 8 " , " s e n d e r " : " p h y " , " i n R e p l y T o " : " f 9 0 a 8 1 f 2 4 4 6 6 5 2 4 8 5 c a 7 3 1 b 0 7 a 5 6 1 e 9 3 " , " s e n t A t " : 1 6 1 5 4 2 0 6 8 6 4 3 0 } } , " r e l a y " : f a l s e } 
])
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a c t i o n " : " s e n d " , " m e s s a g e " : { " c l a z z " : " o r g . a r l . f j a g e . G e n e r i c M e s s a g e " , " d a t a " : { " m s g I D " : " e 2 1 2 4 c 9 c - 0 b 2 9 - 4 c 4 3 - 8 c 2 c - b 8 a d 2 3 8 c 4 1 8 a " , " i n R e p l y T o " : " 2 e 6 9 3 c b d 2 4 1 9 b 8 7 c b f a 9 c b 7 8 f 5 d 8 8 0 b f " , " p e r f " : " A G R E E " , " r e c i p i e n t " : " W e b G W - c e a 1 9 a 9 d 3 7 f b e b 0 8 " , " s e n d e r " : " w e b s h " , " a n s " : " a u t o " } } , " r e l a y " : f a l s e } 
])
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a c t i o n " : " s e n d " , " m e s s a g e " : { " c l a z z " : " o r g . a r l . f j a g e . G e n e r i c M e s s a g e " , " d a t a " : { " m s g I D " : " 1 e f f b 6 8 6 - a 0 5 a - 4 3 a d - a 5 a e - d 7 2 2 d 5 3 4 b b 1 9 " , " i n R e p l y T o " : " d 7 d e c 5 e b 6 a 2 3 d 6 8 3 d 6 8 2 7 3 6 2 c 8 4 d 0 2 8 f " , " p e r f " : " A G R E E " , " r e c i p i e n t " : " W e b G W - c e a 1 9 a 9 d 3 7 f b e b 0 8 " , " s e n d e r " : " w e b s h " , " a n s " : " t c p : / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 : 1 1 0 0 ,   t c p : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 4 : 1 1 0 0 ,   t c p : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 6 5 : 1 1 0 0   [ A P I ] \ n w s : / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 : 8 0 8 0 / w s ,   w s : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 4 : 8 0 8 0 / w s ,   w s : / / 1 9 2 . 1 6 8 . 0 . 1 6 5 : 8 0 8 0 / w s   [ A P I ] \ n t c p : / / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 : 1 1 0 0 / / 1 0 . 0 . 3 . 1 . 3 5 9 5 6   [ A P I ] \ n u n e t s h :   c o n s o l e : / / -   [ G r o o v y S c r i p t E n g i n e ] \ n w e b s h :   w s : / / 1 2 7 . 0 . 1 . 1 : 8 0 8 0 / f j a g e / s h e l l / w s   [ G r o o v y S c r i p t E n g i n e ] " } } , " r e l a y " : f a l s e } 
])
************************************
******* MESSAGE DEBUG PRINT ********
(() . #[{ " a c t i o n " : " s e n d " , " m e s s a g e " : { " c l a z z " : " o r g . a r l . f j a g e . p a r a m . P a r a m e t e r R s p " , " d a t a " : { " i n d e x " : - 1 , " v a l u e s " : n u l l , " p a r a m " : " o r g . a r l . y o d a . M o d e m P a r a m . n o i s e " , " v a l u e " : - I n f i n i t y , " r e a d o n l y " : [ " o r g . a r l . y o d a . M o d e m P a r a m . n o i s e " ] , " m s g I D " : " f a b 5 e 8 4 8 - 4 6 7 6 - 4 1 4 9 - b 6 2 8 - 7 b b 5 a 4 8 2 a 0 f e " , " p e r f " : " I N F O R M " , " r e c i p i e n t " : " W e b G W - c e a 1 9 a 9 d 3 7 f b e b 0 8 " , " s e n d e r " : " p h y " , " i n R e p l y T o " : " a d a 8 d 2 7 1 2 3 6 e 8 d 5 6 0 f 1 7 d 2 9 7 9 e 5 0 2 0 7 4 " , " s e n t A t " : 1 6 1 5 4 2 0 6 8 9 4 3 1 } } , " r e l a y " : f a l s e } 
])
************************************
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::system::system_error'
  what():  End of file

>>> Done (return code -6)
```

[image]

I am trying to send [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064709/remote-access-to-unet-modems-using-json) `JSON` message but the connection was closed before even i do anything.

Is there specific `JSON response` needed by `unetstack` to keep the connection active ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON protocol used by UnetStack is from fjåge. The full specification of the protocol can be found here: https://fjage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol.html

The protocol expects an acknowledgement to the `{"alive": true}` JSON message within a short timeout (5 seconds). If it receives no acknowledgement, it will close the connection, assuming that the connecting party is not responsive. The correct acknowledgement is a `{"alive": true}` sent back to confirm that the connection is indeed alive.

The above handshake is designed to cater for other transports such as RS232 where a disconnection can only be detected by communicating over the connection.

Comment: I agree, I connected successfully as TCP client, and expecting that it should remain open as the connection is still active from `GNURadio` side, same as we connect using `nc tools` i.e `nc 10.0.3.1 1100`. But this closes automatically after successful connection. This seems strange to me.

Comment: It will close unless the client responds with the alive message within 5 seconds. GNUradio won't respond, since it does not speak the fjage JSON protocol. If you use NC, you can manually respond (copy and paste the alive message within 5 seconds) and the connection will stay open.